# Fonts aren't displaying uniformly

Tags: css, fonts, styles, typeface

some elements on my website display perfectly, while other elements of the same font look grainy and choppy. I can't figure out why since I specify the style in the same way.

Here's my website:

http://violetoeuvre.com/

The side bar navigation (me, about, writing contact) is totally fine while the paragraph, h2, and footer styles are grainy and look like a rough version of the same type face.

CSS:

```
    /* Fonts */
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic);
```

Funky styles:

```
h2 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif, 20px;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: 2em;
        color: #000000;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        margin: 0; 
}

h3 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif, 12px;
        font-weight: 100;
        line-height: 2em;
        color: #000000;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        margin: 0; 

}

#foot a:link {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 100;
        color:#000; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}
```

These are functioning fine:

```
#emma_home a:link{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size: 75px;
        font-weight: 200; 
        color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing:-4px;
    }
#nav_menu a:link{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}

#side_wrapper_text a:link{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:#000000;;
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: right;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;

}
```

Also, on a PC the top Emma and Navigation (writing, blog, contact) are about 20 pixels ABOVE the black line, but on my Mac, the letters touch the white like I want.

What gives with these discrepancies??

Thanks.

Comment: What browsers are you using?  You said PC and Mac so I assume at least Safari

Comment: Just a note, your page may not display correctly on mobile devices. Try shrinking your window width and watch what happens.

Comment: Have you met the CSS validator?  http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Thanks everyone - ok, I moved the size to its own line, but it's still not working!!

p {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 2em;
        color: #000000;
        margin: 0; 
}

Comment: @DavidStarkey  - I'm using Chrome, but it looks different (better on a Mac) in the same browser on different computers. I validated and I didn't have any errors for font styling.

Any other suggestions? I'm really lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused as to why Playfair Display appeared grainy in my headings and paragraphs, but NOT in my sidebar navigation.

After some frustration, I realized that the typeface just looks bad at a certain (small) font.

Search for Playfair:

http://www.google.com/fonts/

As you can see, Normal 400 looks very weird, but in larger, bold, or italic styles, it looks just fine.  The only thing to do was to choose a similar typeface for smaller styles, so I'm using Jacques Francois.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should move font-size property from font-family tag
and add it

```
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size : 12px;
```

check this [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) they define 2 properties

Browsers behave differently with css some adapt the error some not

**EDIT**
You can save yourself from repeating code by putting the selector that have same styles mostly and then you can overwrite that style. for ex

```
h2,h3 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
    font-size : 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #000000;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin: 0; 
}
h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I see your `a` link has font weight property double than you defined for other so that may be the case for a tags but i dont see any other significant difference

Comment: @cimmanon i got you but was just showing an example.Thanks for the heads up

Comment: thanks both - ok, i tried that still not working! any suggestions?

Comment: @Claire does this happen in all browsers or just one ?

Comment: @user2125700 I'm using Chrome. It looks better but not great on my Mac than on my PC (but same browser).

Comment: @Claire can you upload a screenshot of mac platform to get a better idea

Comment: @user2125700 Whoa - I noticed looking at google web fonts that the normal style is really scratchy. So perhaps the ragged look has nothing to do with the css styling. 

http://www.google.com/fonts/

(Search for Playfair, there is no url)
Do you see how the Normal 400 looks really weird? perhaps my sidebar navigation is fine just because the font is bigger. 

Weird! I should choose another font for the body, perhaps.
What do you think? 

ALso - if I want to specifcy Bold 700 say, is that just font-style and font-weight? Or is there a way to do that in font-family?

THANKS!

Comment: @Claire .. the other normal 400 text is capitalized so thats why you see the difference but i would suggest you to use more stable and most used fonts on web pages that are consistent and independent of os or browser also to use better coding techniques see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm a designer that works mostly in web but occasionally print as well. I think your issue may actually be with the Playfair font itself which I have just discovered is missing certain font styles when it displays on PCs (Macs look fine). I would test with another font before losing much more time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see IE prefers ttf format over woff and that specific exports is wrong. I simply downloaded the google font mercurial repo any converted original (otf) files with font squirrel, now it works.